# Changing a parameter in a function in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm trying to pass a parameter by reference and update in a function.

```
object CallByName {
  private def inc(x: => Int): Unit = {
    x += 1
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var x = 0
    inc(x)
    println(x)
  }
}
```

But `x+=1` is marked as an error:

> Reassignment to val

I've come across this statement:

> Mutating the input parameters is often seen as bad style and makes it
>   harder to reason about code.

Then how can I alternatively achieve what I want?

Comment: Why do you want to mutate in the fist place? Can't you return the new value?

Comment: This sounds like an **XY Problem**. What do you really want to do and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Mutating the input parameters is often seen as bad style and makes it harder to reason about code.

This is very true and, in my opinion, should be followed at all times.

> pass a parameter by reference

`x: => Int` is not a parameter by reference, it is a [by-name](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) parameter.

> Then how can I alternatively achieve what I want?

```scala
private def inc(x: Int): Int = {
  x + 1
}
var x = 0
x = inc(x)
```

If you do insist on changing input parameter, you can use `AtomicInteger` for example and mutate it within your `inc` method.

Comment: `AtomicInteger` will only mutate the *value*. It will still by pass-by-value. Pass-by-reference means that you can *mutate the reference in the caller's scope*, which is simply not possible in Scala.

Comment: @JörgWMittag The point is that you can still mutate it https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bifxBC7GTJymVTqsGlZPyQ

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to pass a parameter by reference and update in a function.

Scala does not support pass-by-reference. The default is *pass-by-value*, and it is possible to explicitly define individual parameters as *call-by-name*, but those are the only two modes supported.

> ```scala
> object CallByName {
>  private def inc(x: => Int): Unit = {
>    x += 1
>  }
> }
> ```

That's not pass-by-reference, that is call-by-name. Check out the name of the `object`, it says so right there: `CallByName`.

> Then how can I alternatively achieve what I want?

Unfortunately, you don't say what you want to achieve, so it's impossible to say. The only thing you *do* say is that you want pass-by-reference, and for that, the answer is simple:

You can't. Scala does not support pass-by-reference, period.